# iOS - tableview disable refreshing when scrolling down

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, refresh

I'm making a simple "Add to favorites" feature which is a UITableViewController. When the user selected a cell, I set the `color` on gray and disable the `selectionStyle`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
```

My first problem was that everytime I was selecting a cell, some others cells was switching color too. So I deleted the following code for making this not happening :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

But I still have a strange problem : after scrolling down the tableview and then get back to the top of it, I notice that all the cells I've selected were back to the default color, and the last cell selected is highlighted in blue.

So I'm maybe wrong but I'm supposing that the tableview is refreshing when scrolling and I want to disable this behavior.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a fundamental understanding of the way a UITableView presents its subviews (UITableViewCells). I would suggest reading the [UITableView programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html). *Never* remove the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` call on the table view, this is very important for performance.

For your problem: you need to keep track of the state of each cell, and set the state of selection in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, the UITableView reuses cells whenever it can, and refreshes cells when they are scrolled on and off screen.

A very simple implementation would be:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (![self.selectedRows containsObject:indexPath])
        [self.selectedRows addObject:indexPath];
    else
        [self.selectedRows removeObject:indexPath];

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
}
```

and in cellForRow

```
if ([self.selectedRows containsObject:indexPath])
{
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
else
{
    //set the normal cells values
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would not want to disable the most important function the UITableViewController provides because this remove/create trick gives you the fast scrolling you probably want.

As soon as the cells are off the screen (depending on the tableviewcontroller row height) they get deallocated (removed from memory). If it's an incoming cell (from outside the screen) it will be created accordingly in the cellForRowAtIndexPath (creation) method.

You might want to use a `DataSource` for creation and saving states, so it wont loose its properties.

or try this

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 2):

For efficiency, table cells are reused as cells scroll off the screen.  This is normal and desired.  Go with it, don't try to defeat it.

You need to keep track of rows that have been selected somewhere other than the cell itself, because that will be lost when it scrolls off the screen.  I suggest creating a property in your view controller such as an array of NSNumbers which are BOOLs.  When a cell is selected, set the bool to true corresponding to your row, and then you can change the text color of the cell.

When a cell is dequeued, you need to set its color based upon your array.  That will ensure that your cell has the right color as it scrolls on and off the screen.